# Tool to administer Postgres user rights?

Tags: postgresql, tools

I think it is incredibly tedious to administer user rights in Postgres. If I for example want to give editing access to an updatable view, then I need to ensure that the user has the right accesses to, the database, the schema, the underlying table, the sequences used (for inserts), all the columns. So often something goes wrong, also due to my lack of understanding.

However, I don't really see any need to have a deep understanding of this. I can imagine a tool where I could just grant access to the view and the tool would somehow cascade (is that the right expression) the user rights to all needed objects. I understand that this could get difficult to do if giving access to, say, a pl/pgsql function, which touches 100s of objects under various conditions, but for basic objects like views, tables, etc. this should really save me a lot of time.

Please tell me if this question should have been in the softwarerecs StackExchange, I felt that this was the right place, since it is so specific to postgres and, I believe, of general interest.

Comment: You have a "Check Wizard" in pgAdmin, that might help you. BTW: You don't need to "cascade permissions"; it is not necessary. If you grant access to a user so she can `SELECT FROM a_view`, it doesn't mean you have to give her access to the underlying tables. It is the _owner_ of the rule the one that needs access to the underlying table(s).

Comment: Maybe this helps. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools